# Unable to compile project with MvvmCross 3.5 and Unified API

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I tried to migrate a MvvmCross project to Unified API and got stuck at MvvmCross libraries, as soon as I add them, it fails to compile.

To recreate the issue I simply created a new Unified API empty project and added MvvmCross 3.5 NuGet package. Tried to compile and got these errors:

> Setup.cs(8,23): error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>
> DebugTrace.cs(9,27): error CS0012: The type 'System.Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I'm using Xamarin Studio 5.8 for Mac with Xamarin.iOS 8.8.

Shouldn't this work out-of-the-box? Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** Created a new solution from scratch and it works as expected, so I guess it should be something related to the solution file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that deleting `bin` and `obj` folders and a Xamarin Studio restart did the trick. Now everything is worked as expected.